# An uncommon page from IIS will appear?

Tags: iis

When I want to open a created web site, an uncommon page will appear.
You can see it on this page.[image]

Comment: this is not uncommon page, it is IIS default page. could you please provide more details about the issue....did you create a SharePoint Web app?

Comment: its the default IIS server on port **:80** Check what port SharePoint uses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh167832(v=nav.70).aspx

Comment: Is there any body to help me

Comment: you are trying to access your sharepoint site through host headers , can you tell me more about your configurations ?